# How to build cab file from folder with multiple sub-folders and files

Tags: windows

How to make a cab file using a folder with different sub-folders and files using cabarc.exe

I tried with "cabarc.exe n dduout.cab *".
Is there any other ways to build a cabinet file, please let me know any other tools available.